# p:commandButton action in dynamic ui:include doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, javabeans

I'm new at stackoverflow and I hope you can help me.
I have a xhtml page, that includes a composition. In the composition is a `h:form` with a `p:commandbutton` for submitting the `h:form.` The `p:commandbutton` has an action, that should trigger a bean methode, but it doesn't. When i try to put the `p:commandbutton` outside the composition, in the xhtml page, it works.

a little bit code, so you may unterstand my problem a bit better:

The part in the index.xhtml, that includes the composition (This works fine):

```xml
    <p:panel id="centerContentPanel" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px;">
          <ui:include src="#{nCWPBean.centerPanelPage}.xhtml" />
    </p:panel>
```

The composition:

```xml
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:form id="newUserForm">
        <table border="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><h:outputText value="creating a new User"/></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="User Name"/></td>
                    <td><p:inputText id="username" value="#{DBconBean.uname}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="Password"/></td>
                    <td><p:inputText type="password" id="passwordFirst" value="#{DBconBean.pw}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="confirm Password"/></td>
                    <td><p:inputText type="password" id="passwordSecond" value="#{DBconBean.pw2}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h:outputText value="Admin"/></td>
                    <td><p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{DBconBean.rights}" id="adminCheck"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p:commandButton type="submit"  value="Submit"  action="#{DBconBean.insertNewUser()}" icon="ui-icon-check"/></td>
                    <td><p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

     </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

And when I put the whole `p:commandbutton`, with the `action="#{DBconBean.insertNewUser()}"`in the index.html, the methode runs.
That really confuses me...

So, here is my question: How can I trigger a Bean Methode, from a Button in a Composition? Or what did I do wrong?

Oh, and when I try to put in an javascript function, that runs `onsubmit` or `onclick`, it works, until the function contains `#{DBconBean.insertNewUser()};`. In this case the methode is triggerd at the time, the composition loads, not at the time, when the function runs...

Comment: *And when I put the whole `p:commandbutton`, with the `action="#{DBconBean.insertNewUser()}"` in the index.html, the methode runs* So if it works outside `ui:include` are you sure you don't have nested forms?. One `h:form` in page when you include your page and second in including page? Also you can check HTTP response in console (F12) for further debugging. You could find there info like *validation failed* if you had validation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i double checked it now for nested forms and there aren't any.. the last line before the three lines with the include, that i posted, was </h:form>. And I checked the HTTP response as you said: everytime I click the submit button, i get a new HTTP request (I think this is good). The Status-Code is "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" and it contains all values I entered in the form.. This Problem really confuses me :/